# Java Web Service Client Certificate Configuration for Secure(Https) Connections in Jdeveloper

Tags: web-services, oracle, https, certificate, jdeveloper

I'm developing a Web Service integration in Java with Oracle Jdeveloper for UPS shipments. I've imported the WSDL files and they're assigned perfectly. However I can't run it because Jdeveloper throws an exception since it doesn't recognize its certificate. I've downloaded the required certificate and installed it in keystore with keytool commands but nothing changed. Then I've generated a new keystore and installed my certificate in it however Oracle uses DemoIdentity.jks and DemoTrust.jks keystores. I couldn't make Oracle to use my new keystore as default.

Here's the log and the error I'm getting:

```
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:08 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090171> <Loading the identity certificate and private key stored under the alias DemoIdentity from the jks keystore file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\DemoIdentity.jks.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:09 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:09 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\jre\lib\security\cacerts.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:09 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2,OU=(c) 2009 Entrust\, Inc. - for authorized use only,OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms,O=Entrust\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:09 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3,OU=(c) 2008 thawte\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=Certification Services Division,O=thawte\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:09 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:09 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:09 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GlobalSign,O=GlobalSign,OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "OU=Security Communication RootCA2,O=SECOM Trust Systems CO.\,LTD.,C=JP". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority,OU=(c) 2008 VeriSign\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA,OU=ROOT,O=KEYNECTIS,C=FR". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3,OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2,OU=(c) 2009 Entrust\, Inc. - for authorized use only,OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms,O=Entrust\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3,OU=(c) 2008 thawte\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=Certification Services Division,O=thawte\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GlobalSign,O=GlobalSign,OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "OU=Security Communication RootCA2,O=SECOM Trust Systems CO.\,LTD.,C=JP". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority,OU=(c) 2008 VeriSign\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA,OU=ROOT,O=KEYNECTIS,C=FR". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3,OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<26.Oca.2013 14:02:10 EET> <Warning> <Security> <BEA-090504> <Certificate chain received from localhost - 127.0.0.1 --> wwwcie.ups.com failed hostname verification check. Certificate contained MST-PC(My computer name) but check expected wwwcie.ups.com>
```

Please give me your ideas on how to solve this problem. Any recommed would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

P.S: I'm using Oracle JDeveloper 11g Release 1, jdk160_24, Weblogic Server 10.3, Win7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, is the SSL one-way or two-way?

One-way means that only the service server (the one that has the WS you are trying to access) must identify with you. In order for the service server to identify with you, you must download the certificates it provides from its page (loads of tutorials on how to do this). WARNING: you HAVE to get the whole certificate chain! Add those certificates to your Trust keystore.

Two-way means that you also have to identify with them. To do this you should have gotten an certificate from the service provider and added it to your clients Identity keystore.

At this point you should have 2 separate keystores. One, Trust keystore, is the store that holds all the certificates of servers that are safe (you trust them, hence the name). Second is the Identity keystore, the store that holds your identity under certain alias. Other servers will use this information to determine if they trust you.

Now for WLS configuration:

First, if you're going to use SSL do not use Demo Identity and Demo Trust setting. Change it to Custom Identity and Custom Trust. Set the keystores to the ones you created. If the server will be using only one-way SSL then you can set identity store to Demo Identity, but it still has to be done under Custom Identity and Custom Trust settings (just copy paths, passwords, etc from default). Setup the Identity under server->SSL and you are done.

Other:

You might want to turn off Hostname Verification (Server->SSL->Advanced). This sometimes 
causes a lot of problems.

If still does not work, add following flags to java options:

-Dweblogic.security.SSL.verbose=true

-Dweblogic.security.SSL.enable.renegotiation=true

-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true

Comment: It's a SSL one-way. There is a certificate chain, yes. And I've installed all of them to the keystore I've created. However I couldn't manage to change default keystore from DemoIdentity and DemoTrust. I still don't know how to change them to custom identity and custom trust.                                                                                               I assume I should add the flags at the end of your post to WebLogic startup script.                                                                    I hope I can get more help from you. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Enter your console window (http://server:7001/console). Set the session to edit (look to upper left corner of the window) and click through following: servers->your managed server->configuration->keystores. In this window you will see "Demo Identity and Demo Trust" with a button next to it called "Change". Click it and a window with keystore options should show. Choose us you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Recent updates to the Sun JDK (Java Developer Kit) (versions: 1.6.0_13 and 1.5.0_18) are incompatible with the SSL (Secure Socket Layer) implementation in the following versions of Oracle WebLogic Server:

- 11gR1 (10.3.1)
- 10gR3 (10.3.0)
- 10.0 and all maintenance releases of 10.0
- 9.0, 9.1, 9.2 and all maintenance releases of 9.2 prior to 9.2 MP4
  Oracle JRockit versions from R27.6.4 (1.6.0_13 and 1.5.0_18) and higher also exhibit this issue.

Workaround

1) Use an earlier version of JDK - JDK1.6.0_12 and earlier will be ok.

```
 or
```

2)  Replace the trust store file of \jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts with one from earlier JDK